# Не отображаются картинки в админке MODX Revo на вкладке файлы

Tags: файлы, modx, revo

Решил минифицировать изображения. Старые удалил через админку на хостинге timeweb, новые с прежними названиями загрузил через админку MODX, и теперь MODX делает вид, что их нет, хотя хостинг изображения видит, и на сайте всё загружается. С чем может быть связана проблема?

Версия CMF: MODX Revolution 2.5.7-pl

Comment: Возможно кеш CMS

Comment: Кеш чистил, не помогает

Comment: Админка то старая, все, что ниже 2.6.0 бомбят вирусами страшно! Проверь на наличие подозрительных файлов в сайте или открой index.php - есть ли код в начале странный